# Hexagons and Pentagons UV map

Tags: uv

How I can create UV map with pentagons in center and hexagons around? But without gap between hexagons and pentagons.

[image]

---

Thanks, now, how can I make all the hexagons have all the pages be equal?[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a UV workspace and..

1. On the 3D side, select a pentagonal face, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar > Polygon sides*
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> expand the selection to include surrounding Hexagons
3. Edge Mode, Header *Select* Menu > *Loops* > *Select Boundary Loops* and ..
4. Right-click, > *Mark Seams*

With those faces selected, <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap. This will unwrap the pentagons and their surrounding hexes to separate, identical islands. If you want them all overlapped, those can be snapped together, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to the  cursor.. but I must say, haven't figured out a way to do them all simultaneously.

[image]

This leaves a ribbon of hexes between the islands, so I (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, by inverse) selected them, and <kbd>U</kbd> > *Reset* those.. it all depends what you want.